# How to put KeepAliveValues for a TCP socket in docker, even on a Windows environment?

Tags: c#, windows, docker, sockets, windows-10

I'm working on my first Docker application, and I would like to configure the KeepAlive settings. In the old Windows environment, this was working fine like this:

```
[SupportedOSPlatform("windows")]
public static void ... (...)
{
    Socket socket = ...;
    bool useKeepAlive = ...;
    int keepAliveInterval = ...;
    int retryInterval = ...;

    byte[] KAValues = new byte[size * 3];
    Array.Copy(BitConverter.GetBytes(on), 0, KAValues, 0, size);
    Array.Copy(BitConverter.GetBytes(keepAliveInterval), 0, KAValues, size, size);
    Array.Copy(BitConverter.GetBytes(retryInterval), 0, KAValues, size * 2, size);

    socket.IOControl(IOControlCode.KeepAliveValues, KAValues, null);
...
```

While trying to execute this code in a docker-based application, the last line generates a `PlatformNotSupportedException`.

The compiler (intellisense, in fact) generates a warning `CA1416` on the `IOControlCode.KeepAliveValues` part, mentioning that this piece of code is supported on Windows. Now I am working on a Windows machine indeed, but I believe that the Docker-based environment messes this up.

**Edit1**: I've added the "attribute" `[SupportedOSPlatform("windows")]` just before the declaration of the function, but this did not solve the issue.

**Edit2**
I had a look at my projectfile, where I found following entries:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <UserSecretsId>7505f631-669c-4db7-ay10-4fc92e9b4b79</UserSecretsId>
    <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
    <DockerfileContext>..\..\..</DockerfileContext>
    <DockerComposeProjectPath>..\..\docker-compose.dcproj</DockerComposeProjectPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

As you can see, the "DockerDefaultTargetOS" seems to be "Linux", while I'm working with Windows machines.

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65554661/wsl2-docker-keep-alive-bug-in-tcp-stack?force_isolation=true

Comment: @jdweng: I'm sorry, but your proposal seems to explain why my code is superfluous on a Linux system, but I'm not working on Linux, I'm working on Windows-based machines.

Comment: The link refers to a docker interface.  Docker should work same either on Windows or Linux.

Comment: @jdweng: Are you saying that the `PlatformNotSupportedException` is not caused by the fact that I'm working with Docker? Do you know where my application might be getting the platform information from, which is responsible for this exception? (Don't forget that the `KeepAlive` is mentioned being supported by Windows while both my machine and the connected machine are both Windows (Windows-10) machines)

Comment: You are forgetting the interfaces between c#, docker, core, and OS.  Both docker and core have to support the methods.  See : https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/34838

Comment: @Dominique I would disregard everything said by jdweng, they are well-known for posting confusing and incorrect (and sometimes dangerous) comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WSL2 Linux docker containers run on top of a virtualized Linux kernel, not the Windows kernel like they did in WSL1. So it's just like installing Linux in a Hyper-V VM and running Docker on the Linux VM.